# How to write in to a text file at specific locations in java?

Tags: java, text, file-io

I am trying to create a text file and in that text file i have different columns of different size and i have to write accordingly in that file,
I have tried like that .....
but I dont know how to define the size for each column for example i want the location for size 30 not less not more how can i do that ?

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        String none=" ";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
         Date date = new Date();
         int no_of_files=01;

        String line1 = "H"+StringUtils.rightPad(none,9)+dateFormat.format(date)+StringUtils.rightPad(none,8)+" "+no_of_files+StringUtils.rightPad(none,10)+StringUtils.rightPad(none,290);
        String line2 =StringUtils.rightPad("CID",10)+StringUtils.rightPad("Location",30)+StringUtils.rightPad("DateSF",8)+StringUtils.rightPad("DateST",8)+StringUtils.rightPad("BillAmt",10)+StringUtils.rightPad("BR",2)+StringUtils.rightPad("PDF FileName",260);






        File file = new File("D:\\write.txt");


        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));


        bw.write(line1);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(line2);
       // writer.write(line2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null) {
                bw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what you have tried and what problem you are facing?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  See the [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) tutorial for a starting point.

Comment: @Jimmt  What if it is?  The [tag:homework] tag has been retired and all questions are to be treated the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into using this function from Commons-IO to help keep the length of each column the same.

[StringUtils.rightPad()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#rightPad%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: Can you please  give me a head start ??

Comment: Once you know the size of each "column" you can call this function with the value you want to put in the column and the size of the column.  Then append them all together with a StringBuilder.

Comment: the problem i am facing is how can i set the size for columns once it is done it will be easy for me , I am new to java that's why asking , sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I did a little framework that lets you define a layout in a spring file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC  "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"   "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans> 
<bean id="merchantNumber" class="com.xxx.io.Field">
    <property name="name"><value>merchantNumber</value></property>
    <property name="length"><value>8</value></property>
    <property name="scale"><value>0</value></property>
    <property name="type"><value>7</value></property>
    <property name="index"><value>1</value></property>
</bean>
<bean id="merchantName" class="com.xxx.io.Field">
    <property name="name"><value>merchantName</value></property>
    <property name="length"><value>40</value></property>
    <property name="scale"><value>0</value></property>
    <property name="type"><value>2</value></property>
    <property name="index"><value>2</value></property>
</bean>
```

```
<bean id="marchandLayout" class="com.xxx.MarchandLayout" >
<property name="fields">
<bean class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
          <entry>
            <key><value>merchantNumber</value></key>
            <ref bean="merchantNumber"/>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <key><value>merchantName</value></key>
            <ref bean="merchantName"/>
          </entry>
```

From then on you create a class that creates a FileExport (which writes in a fileOutputStream) using the recordLayout defined in Spring.

I've also added a functionnality that reads a sequential file and stores the values in the layout attributes.

If you're interested, I will send you the source code.

hope it helps.

RecordLayout Class :
    package com.xxx.io;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class RecordLayout {

private HashMap          fields;

private static final int SEVENTY = 70;

/**
 * Constructeur
 */
public RecordLayout() {
    fields = new HashMap();
}

/**
 * @param aField
 *            le champ à ajouter dans le HashMap
 */
protected void addField(final Field aField) {
    fields.put(aField.getName(), aField);
}

/**
 * Methode qui retourne un objet de type Field en passant en parametre le
 * nom du champ.
 * 
 * @param aFieldName
 *            le nom de l'objet à récuperer
 * @return un objet de type Field
 * @throws FieldException
 *             si le Field n'est pas trouvable dans le HashMap, on retourne
 *             une exception
 */
public Field getField(final String aFieldName) throws FieldException {

    Field field = (Field) fields.get(aFieldName);
    if (field == null) {
        throw new FieldException("Field " + aFieldName + " n'existe pas dans le layout");
    }
    return field;
}

/**
 * méthode qui retourne un iterator contenant une collection d'objet de type
 * Field en fonction de l'ordre basé sur le champ de l'index de l'objet
 * 
 * @see Field.getIndex()
 * @see Field.compareTo()
 * @return un iterator
 */
protected Iterator getOrderedFieldIterator() {
    TreeSet structureTreeSet = new TreeSet(fields.values());
    return structureTreeSet.iterator();
}

/**
 * Retourne la valeur de l'objet Field
 * 
 * @param aFieldName
 *            le nom du champ à recherché.
 * @return retourne l'objet qui contient la valeur. String, BigDecimal
 * @throws FieldException
 *             si le champ n'existe pas, une exception est lancée.
 */
public Object getValue(final String aFieldName) throws FieldException {
    return getField(aFieldName).getValue();
}

/**
 * Cette méthode assigne une valeur à un objet.
 * 
 * @param aName
 *            le nom de l'objet, le Field
 * @param aValue
 *            la valeur à assigner au Field
 * @throws FieldException
 *             si le Field n'existe pas.
 */
public void setValue(final String aName, final Object aValue) throws FieldException {
    getField(aName).setValue(aValue);
}

/**
 * Cette méthode prend la valeur des champs, en fonction de l'ordre des
 * champs et parcours les valeurs et les mets dans un stream.
 * 
 * @return un stream contenant les données des objets comme dans un layout
 *         de fichier plat.
 * @throws Exception
 *             si une exception arrive lors de la transformation
 */
public ByteArrayOutputStream toByteArray() throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream anOutputStream;

    try {
        anOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(SEVENTY);
        toStream(anOutputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("Unexpected at the toByte Creation ");
    }
    return anOutputStream;
}

/**
 * Méthode qui itère sur la collection et qui appelle la transformation des
 * valeurs objets en objets String
 * 
 * @param anOutputStream
 *            le stream contenant les valeurs
 * @throws FieldException
 *             Si une erreur survient au niveau des champs
 * @throws IOException
 *             si une erreur survient au niveau du stream.
 */
public void toStream(final OutputStream anOutputStream) throws FieldException, IOException {
    Iterator iterator;
    iterator = getOrderedFieldIterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Field field = (Field) iterator.next();
        field.toStream(anOutputStream);
    }
}

/**
 * Méthode qui prend un inputStream et qui crée les objets
 * 
 * @param message
 *            le contenu du stream
 * @throws FieldException
 *             si une erreur de Field survient
 * @throws IOException
 *             si une erreur survient au niveau du stream.
 */
public void buildFromStream(final InputStream message) throws FieldException, IOException {
    Iterator iterator;
    iterator = getOrderedFieldIterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        ((Field) iterator.next()).initializeFrom(message);
    }
}

/**
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 * @return  String rprésentation
 */
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Iterator it = getOrderedFieldIterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Field f = (Field) it.next();
        sb.append(f.getName() + " = [" + f.getValue() + "]\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

/**
 * @return le HashMap contenant les champs
 */
public HashMap getFields() {
    return fields;
}

/**
 * @param map
 *            à setter
 */
public void setFields(final HashMap map) {
    fields = map;
}
```

}

Comment: @Abhi I have never done anything like this , so dont know from where to start ??

Comment: You need to define the fields in the xml file and also define the recordLayout in the spring file. Once this is done, you need to create a process that will take your bean and set it in your recordLayout object => aRecrdLayoutObject.getField("merchantNumber").setValue(my.bean.getMerchantNumber(); once this is done, you take the recordLayout.toStream which write the fields in the order defined in the spring file and writes them in a file

Comment: hey I am not using spring , can you tell me different way please ...

Comment: you need to know the basics of Java. Have no time to teach... sorry

Comment: Hey can you send me the source code please ?